# Creating groups using MySQL

Tags: mysql, case, grouping, case-when

I want to group together 4 values in a column, as well as add an all-inclusive group. My closest attempt is:

```
case
when 'color' = 'blue' then 'Blue'
when 'color' = 'red' then 'Red'
when 'color' = 'green' then 'Green'
when 'color' = 'orange' then 'Orange'
else 'Other'
end
```

But I can't get the all-inclusive group in that same statement. I'm actually in the marketing department, so my SQL knowledge is limited.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the all-inclusive group?

Comment: The all-inclusive group would be when color = anything

Comment: Get rid of the quotes around `'color'`, otherwise you're testing against the word "color" and not the column value.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What should the result look like?

Comment: Are you trying to match against a search term? So someone can put `Any` in the color field of a search form and it will match any color?

Comment: The way to do that is to leave out the color test from the `WHERE` clause of the query.

Comment: can you put an example of how to use `where` to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Lose the quotes around column names. It turns them into static strings and not column values.

```
case when color = 'blue' then 'Blue'
     when color = 'red' then 'Red'
     when color = 'green' then 'Green'
     when color = 'orange' then 'Orange'
     else 'Other'
end
```

Comment: how then do I define a category that contains all colors?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. Please add some example data and expected output to your question.

Comment: `case when color = 'blue' or
     when color = 'red' or
     when color = 'green' or
     when color = 'orange' or
     then 'All Colors'
end`

but I want that inside of the other statement that defines each individual color also.

Comment: Maybe something like this?

`case when 'color' in ('red','blue','orange','green','yellow','black','pink','purple','white') then 'all'
when 'color' = 'blue' then 'blue'
else 'other'
end`

Comment: Put the `set` case first: `case when LeadStatus = 'set' then 'set' when LeadStatus in ('dead','set','could not set','duplicate','wnd','created from job','call to reschedule','ooa','raw','call back','raw - evening call back','recycle') then 'all leads'  else 'other' end`